# Executing asynchronously but writing synchronously

Tags: ios, cocoa, concurrency, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have this situation: a video must be processed frame by frame but as frames are being processed, the output have to be write to file in sequence.

I want to fire asynchronous blocks using `dispatch_async` to a concurrent queue to speed the process but because this queue is asynchronous I don't see how I will coordinate to write the frames serially to the output.

Suppose this situation: frames 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are sent to concurrent queues for processing. Because any block can finish at any time, frame 4 may be the first to finish, followed by 5, 3, 1, 2. So how will I manage to write the frames in the sequential order to the output?

I have a code like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

while (true) {

    video >> frame;  // read a frame from the video

    dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{
         processVideo(frame, outputFrame);
         writeToVideo(outputFrame); // this is here just to show what needs to be done
    });

    // bla bla

}
```

any clues?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a combination of a serial dispatch queue and an [`NSCondition`](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/). The serial queue makes sure that none of the writes happen concurrently, while the `NSCondition` makes sure that they happen in the correct order.

From the `NSCondition` docs:

> A condition object acts as both a lock and a checkpoint in a given
>   thread. The lock protects your code while it tests the condition and
>   performs the task triggered by the condition. The checkpoint behavior
>   requires that the condition be true before the thread proceeds with
>   its task. While the condition is not true, the thread blocks.

In your specific situation I'd do something like this...

In your loop you first declare a `BOOL` (initially set to `NO`) which indicates if your frame has been processed or not, and an `NSCondition`. Then, `dispatch_async` to both the background queue to process frame, and the serial queue to write the data.

When the block in the serial queue runs, lock the `NSCondition` and then check the `BOOL` to see if the frame has been processed. If it has, proceed with the write. If it hasn't, `wait` for a `signal` from the `NSCondition` and check again when it receives it. When it's done, `unlock` the `NSCondition`.

When the block in the background queue runs, lock the `NSCondition` and process the frame. When the frame is processed, set the `BOOL` to indicate that the frame is processed. Then `signal` and `unlock` the `NSCondition`.

***Note:** It's important that you only access the `BOOL` that indicates that the frame is processed and your `outputFrame` inside the `NSCondition`'s lock; the lock is making sure they stay synchronized between threads.*

```
// Create the background and serial queues
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_queue_t writeQueue = dispatch_queue_create("writeQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

while (true) { // I'm assuming you have some way to break out of this...
    NSCondition *condition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];

    // These need the __block attribute so they can be changed inside the blocks
    __block BOOL frameProcessed = NO;
    __block FrameType outputFrame = nil;

    // video >> frame;  // read a frame from the video

    // dispatch the frame for processing
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        [condition lock];

        processVideo(frame, outputFrame);
        frameProcessed = YES;

        [condition signal];
        [condition unlock];
    });

    // dispatch the write
    dispatch_async(writeQueue, ^{
        [condition lock];
        while (!frameProcessed) {
            [condition wait]; // this will block the current thread until it gets a signal
        }

        writeToVideo(outputFrame);

        [condition unlock];
    });
}
```

***Note:** There is a semi-subtle trick with `BOOL frameProcessed` in the above code too. Since it's declared inside the loop instead of outside, each block will capture the one associated with its frame.*

---

**Update:** Adding an `NSCondition` for reading as well.

> Because writing to video is slow compared to the parallel execution,
>   zillions of frames are allocated and sit in memory until they are
>   saved to disk.

I would handle this is by throttling the reads using another `NSCondition` which blocks your reads if there are too many frames waiting to be written in your `writeQueue`. The concept is almost identical to the `NSCondition` we added before, it's just a different condition; in this cast it would be an `int` that indicates how many frames are waiting to be written.

Before your loop, define a `readCondition`, `writeQueueSize` and `maxWriteQueueSize`. Inside the loop, first `lock` the `readCondition`, check if `writeQueueSize >= maxWriteQueueSize`. If it isn't, continue on with reading a frame and queuing up the processing and writing. Just before you dispatch to the `writeQueue`, increment `writeQueueSize`. Then `unlock` `readCondition`.

Then, inside the block dispatched to `writeQueue`, once the write is complete, `lock` `readCondition`, decrement `writeQueueSize`, and `signal` and `unlock` `readCondition`.

That should ensure that there are never more than `maxWriteQueueSize` blocks waiting in the `writeQueue`. If there are that many blocks waiting, it'll effectively pause the reading of frames from the video until the `writeQueue` is ready for more.

```
// Create the background and serial queues
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_queue_t writeQueue = dispatch_queue_create("writeQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

NSCondition *readCondition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
__block int writeQueueSize = 0;
const int maxWriteQueueSize = 10;

while (true) { // I'm assuming you have some way to break out of this...
    NSCondition *writeCondition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];

    // These need the __block attribute so they can be changed inside the blocks
    __block BOOL frameProcessed = NO;
    __block FrameType outputFrame = nil;

    [readCondition lock];
    while (writeQueueSize >= maxWriteQueueSize) {
        [readCondition wait];
    }

    // video >> frame;  // read a frame from the video

    // dispatch the frame for processing
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        [writeCondition lock];

        processVideo(frame, outputFrame);
        frameProcessed = YES;

        [writeCondition signal];
        [writeCondition unlock];
    });

    // dispatch the write
    writeQueueSize++; // Increment the write queue size here, before the actual dispatch
    dispatch_async(writeQueue, ^{
        [writeCondition lock];
        while (!frameProcessed) {
            [writeCondition wait]; // this will block the current thread until it gets a signal
        }

        writeToVideo(outputFrame);

        [writeCondition unlock];

        // Decrement the write queue size and signal the readCondition that it changed
        [readCondition lock];
        writeQueueSize--;
        [readCondition signal];
        [readCondition unlock];
    });

    [readCondition unlock];
}
```

Comment: FANTASTIC! This is simply brilliant!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Can't upvote you enough!!!!

Comment: There is only one issue with this method, is that because writing to video is slow compared to the parallel execution, zillions of frames are allocated and sit in memory until they are saved to disk. Memory usage escalated from 42 Mb to 2 GB in 10 seconds!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)  I updated my answer with a way to throttle your reads so that you don't overwhelm your write queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by giving each frame its own result queue, and chaining all the queues together in order. We suspend all the queues except the first one. Then as each frame finishes, it resumes the next result queue. This will force the queues to deliver their results in the order we want, regardless of when they complete their work.

Here's an example that just uses `sleep` to simulate some random amount of work and prints the results in the correct order. The `dispatch_group` is used here to prevent the program from exiting too soon. You might not need it in your case.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    for (unsigned x = 1; x <= 5; x++ ) {

      // Chain the queues together in order; suspend all but the first.
      dispatch_queue_t subQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
      dispatch_set_target_queue(subQueue, myQueue);
      dispatch_suspend(subQueue);

      dispatch_group_async(group, mainQueue,^{

        // Perform a random amount of work
        u_int32_t sleepTime = arc4random_uniform(10);
        NSLog(@"Sleeping for thread %d (%d)", x, sleepTime);
        sleep(sleepTime);

        // OK, done with our work, queue our printing, and tell the next guy he can print
        dispatch_sync(myQueue, ^{
          printf("%d ", x);
          dispatch_resume(subQueue);
        });
      });

      myQueue = subQueue;
    }

    // Wait for the whole group to finish before terminating
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  }

  return 0;
}
```